# Future[Try[Book]] vs Future[Book] in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I was suggested to use `Future[Book]` rather than `Future[Try[Book]]` in a pull request review.

Why is that?

If I use `Future[Book]`, then how I can convert Success or Failure. Is it not clear to me at all.

If we use Future[Book], we are completely losing the notion of success and failure in Scala.

Comment: A **Future** is like an asynchronous **Try** so, in general, it doesn't make much sense to have one inside another. A **Future**  also has a concept of success and failure and equally to **Try** all failures are `Exceptions`. So that is why, sometimes tho it makes sense to have a notion of domain errors vs exceptions, but for that, it is common to use `Future[Either[DomainError, A]]` where `DomainError` is usually ADT, also on those cases it is common to use `EitherT` from **cats**. - In any case, you should be asking this to whoever code review you :)

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. I have not understood the code review and was comments were harsh :-( So trying to do my due diligence.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, the resulting value of a future is wrapped in either a `Success` or `Failure` type, which is a type of `Try`. Hence, the value in a Future is always an instance of one of the `Try` types: `Success` or `Failure`.

Since these are `Try` types, you can register a callback on a future which accepts a `Try` type. An example is to use the `onComplete` which takes a callback function of type `Try[T] => U` and returns a `Unit`.

```
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

val f: Future[List[String]] = Future {
  session.getUserNamesFromDatabase
}

f onComplete {
  case Success(users) => for (user <- users) println(user)
  case Failure(t) => println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
}
```

The benefit of a callback on a future is that it can complete without blocking the client. So the callback can execute completely asynchronously.

**Note:** that the `onComplete` method has a `unit` return type. So it cannot be chained.